# Logging errors in axis2 webservice

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

In my axis2 webservice, I want to log all possible errors to a log file. I am confused with where to store the log4j.properties file in the .aar file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Java || .Net prgmng? IDE ? If you are looking for, how to use log 4j with eclipse, then --> [This helps !!](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/log4j-logging-inside-eclipse-console)

Comment: thanks for the your help, but that won't help me in my case. I want to log errors in my axis2 web service. And in my case it is not  generating the log file.